# changing the value of submit button after form submit

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have form with submit button ,when i submit the form the value of the button should insert into the databse and change text of button to **inserted**.if the insertion is not possible(violates  constraint) change the text of button to **not inserted**

```
<html>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <button type="submit" name="button1" value="one" id="bttn">CLICK</button>
    </form>
</html>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['button1']))
    {
        $a=$_POST['button1'];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","PROJECT8","PROJECT8");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"PROJECT8");
    $rs=mysqli_query($con,"insert into ruff values('$a')");
        if($rs)
        {

            //if data is inserted i need to change the button text to "inserted"
        }
        else
        {
            //change the button text to "not inserted"

        }
    }
?>
```

i searched  about and it shows you need to use AJAX i am a newbie in AJAX
the complete code will be very helpfull

Comment: First, try to fill in the `action` part of your `<form>` tag. That needs to point at the file that handles the POST request. Also, this is question doesn't seem to be AJAX related. AJAX requests would involve some Javascript code as well, which you don't have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code in your case,

```
if($rs) {
   echo "<script>
        document.getElementById('bttn').innerHTML = 'inserted';
   </script>";
}
else {
  echo "<script>
        document.getElementById('bttn').innerHTML = 'not inserted';
  </script>";      
}
```